# How do I always return the value from an enum as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I am using Python 3.9.6.  I am trying to write more readable code by using enums.  The enums are being used for REST API output.  In the example below the output from the enum MUST be a string and look like MON.  In all caps.  So in short I always want the output from the enum to be the value of the enum and be returned as an actual string.

#1 below is how I 'want' to use the enum.  Passing a list of days to a function.  Unfortunately the object detail is printed.

#5 and #6 below have the correct output but I find the usage clumsy and would prefer the usage in #1

Is there a way to always return the enum value as a string?

```
from enum import Enum
class Days(Enum):
    Mon = 'MON'
    def __str__(self):
        print( '*******' )
        return f'{self.value}'
    # def __format__(self, spec):
    #   return f'{self.value}'

# under any condition I want to ALWAYS 
# return the enum value as a string
print( '1:' )   # Use enum --> (output NOT correct)'            
print( [Days.Mon] )
print( '2:' )   # Force Usage of __str__' )                 
print( f'{Days.Mon}' )          
print( '3: ' )  # This works because it calls __str__' )                
print( Days.Mon )  
print( '4:' )   # Example List of strings (correct)' )              
print( ['Mon'] )
print( '5:' )   # Don't want to force my users to do this' 
print( str([Days.Mon.value]) )  
print( '6:' )   # Don't want to do this'                    
print( [f'{Days.Mon}'] )
```

Output looks like this:

```
1:
[<Days.Mon: 'MON'>]
2:
*******
MON
3: 
*******
MON
4:
['Mon']
5:
['MON']
6:
*******
['MON']
```

Comment: There's `enum.StrEnum`, but it sounds like you might be better off just using a bunch of ordinary strings, without an enum.

Answer (score 2):

You want to define `__repr__` also, because `list.__str__` calls the `__repr__` method of the list's elements.

```
from enum import Enum
class Days(Enum):
    Mon = 'MON'

    def __str__(self):
        # Since self.value is already a string, formatting it 
        # using an f-string is pointless
        # Just return it directly
        return self.value 

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

Now, printing a list containing `Days` instances will print the instances as their string representation:

```
>>> print([Days.Mon])
# ['MON']
```

Here's some more information on the differences between `__str__` and `__repr__`: https://realpython.com/python-repr-vs-str/

As [@user2357112 noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77063487/how-do-i-always-return-the-value-from-an-enum-as-a-string/77063766#comment135862844_77063766), changing the `__repr__` makes your objects look like strings, but they aren't actually strings. If I were in your place, I'd change the `__repr__` to return something like `Days('MON')` to make it clear that the object is an instance of the `Days` class. You shouldn't rely on the builtin `list.__str__` to build your API output.

Comment: Perfect!! that worked.  I had tried __repr__() as well but did not include the repr() wrapper.  What the heck does that do?  Also Pythons official example for __repr__() does not include that return wrapper.

Comment: @Keith That wrapper simply calls the `__repr__` method of `self.value`. Since `self.value` is a string, `str.__repr__` gives you the contents of the string, surrounded by `'`. We could have also done `return f"\'{self.value}\'"` instead to explicitly do the same thing

Comment: This just makes your objects *look like* strings. They won't actually be strings. Anything that needs a real string will fail if you pass `Days.Mon`.

Comment: @user2357112 you make a fair point and I've added a note to my answer